# Formatted outline text on QImage

Tags: c++, qt

How to draw outline text on `QImage` with word wrap, alignment etc.?

I tried `QPainterPath::addText()` method, but it does not support word wrap and alignment.

This is how I draw text now:

```
path.addText(rect.bottomLeft(), font, text);
p.strokePath(path, pen);
p.drawText(rect, flag, text);
```

where

- `p` - `QPainter`
- `rect` - rectangle that contains the text
- `flag` - `Qt::AlignRight`, `Qt::TextWordWrap`

but it looks like this

[image]

Comment: You could place an image of what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc obviously the outline is supposed to be around the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution: I draw the text in the buffer (using QPainter.drawText), calculate the SDF, and make outline.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function

https://blog.mapbox.com/drawing-text-with-signed-distance-fields-in-mapbox-gl-b0933af6f817

Comment: Hi! Can you post your working code? I am searching a simple outline text soliton but i still did not find what is my goul :(

Answer (score 0):

`QPainter` does not support this and neither does `QPainterPath`.

What you can do is use a `QGraphicsScene`instead. If you really have to create a `QImage`, you can always do that using its `render()` function.

To achieve this effect in a graphics scene you need a `QGraphicsTextItem` and a `QTextCharFormat`.
The outline is painted on top of the actual text, which looks like complete crap for any outline thicker than `1`. Therefore you have to add another `QGraphicsTextItem` without outline on top of the first one.

Here is a full running example. Note that we can specify the width of the text, but not the height, you wold probably do that by clipping.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextCharFormat>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    QFont font("Arial", 30);
    QRect rect(100, 100, 300, 0);

    QImage img(500, 500, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    img.fill(0x00ffffff);
    {
        QPainter p(&img);

        QGraphicsScene scene(img.rect());

        QTextCharFormat charFormat;
        charFormat.setFont(font);
        charFormat.setTextOutline(QPen(Qt::red, 5, Qt::SolidLine));

        QTextDocument document;
        QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(&document);
        cursor.insertText(text, charFormat);

        QGraphicsTextItem outlineTextItem;
        outlineTextItem.setPos(rect.topLeft());
        outlineTextItem.setDocument(&document);
        outlineTextItem.setTextWidth(rect.width());
        scene.addItem(&outlineTextItem);

        QGraphicsTextItem textItem(text);
        textItem.setPos(rect.topLeft());
        textItem.setTextWidth(rect.width());
        textItem.setFont(font);
        scene.addItem(&textItem);

        scene.render(&p);
    }

    QLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(std::move(img)));
    label.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In your version, the text fits into a rectangle and the size is selected automatically. In your variant the text differs from QPainter.drawText.
I found this solution: I draw the text in the buffer (using QPainter.drawText), calculate the SDF, and make outline.

Comment: @RuslanAkhmetshin This solution answers the question you actually posted, in my opinion. Also I don't understand whatever additional requirement you just added with your comment. However if you do have a different solution, please post it.